# JQuery get values from html table

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, object, html-table

I am attempting to pull data from a dynamic table using JQuery, but every way I've tried turns the values into something else (the below code will return an "l" instead of the N/A I was expecting.  I have tried using .each and .map as the function as well as .val .html and as you can see .text to pull the data.  I am stuck as to why and what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
    <table id="attendees" class="attendees">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border-bottom: double;border-color: #007fff" ;="">
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Membership Type</th>
            <th>Membership Expiration Date</th>
            <th>Free Vouchers</th>
            <th>Classes From Pack Remaining</th>
            <th>Yelp Check in</th>
            <th>Payment Option</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>Students Name</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <ul id="list">
                    <select id="payment" name="payment">
                        <option>Cash/Credit</option>
                        <option>Free Voucher</option>
                        <option>Yelp Check-in</option>
                    </select>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><a href="#" class="remove"><p>Remove</p></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#submit").live('click', function (e) {
           $("#attendees tr.data").map(function (index, elem) {
               var x = $(this);
               var cells = x.find('td');
               var $data = cells.text();
               //alert($data[1]);
                if ($data[1] == "N/A") {
                alert(true);    
               }

          });
            e.preventDefault();

        });
```

**Final Solution**

Thanks first of all to everyone who chimed in, I honestly learned a little something from each persons answer.  In the end this is what I settled on below.  In hindsight I probably should of given a more thorough description on what I was attempting to accomplish.  Which was to scan multiple rows of data and do something based on the info found in each row.  To accomplish this I was forced to separate the `tr` and `td` `.each` functions.  This allowed me to scan row by row and still get the individual data.
Thanks again for everyone's help  especially @TechHunter

```
$("#submit").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#attendees tbody tr").each(function(i) {
    var $data= [];
    var x = $(this);
    var cells = x.find('td');
    $(cells).each(function(i) {
    var $d= $("option:selected", this).val()||$(this).text();
    $data.push($d);
    });      
        if ($data[1] == "N/A") {
           doSomething(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest answer would be to add a class when you need to retrieve a value :

**HTML**

```
<table id="attendees" class="attendees">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border-bottom: double;border-color: #007fff" ;="">
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Membership Type</th>
            <th>Membership Expiration Date</th>
            <th>Free Vouchers</th>
            <th>Classes From Pack Remaining</th>
            <th>Yelp Check in</th>
            <th>Payment Option</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="data">
            <td class="inputValue">Students Name</td>
            <td class="inputValue">N/A</td>
            <td class="inputValue">N/A</td>
            <td class="inputValue">0</td>
            <td class="inputValue">0</td>
            <td class="inputValue">Yes</td>
            <td>
                <ul id="list">
                    <select id="payment" class="inputValue" name="payment">
                        <option>Cash/Credit</option>
                        <option>Free Voucher</option>
                        <option>Yelp Check-in</option>
                    </select>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><a href="#" class="remove"><p>Remove</p></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#submit").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#attendees tr.data").map(function (index, elem) {
        var ret = [];
        $('.inputValue', this).each(function () {
            var d = $(this).val()||$(this).text();
            ret.push(d);
            console.log(d);
            if (d == "N/A") {
                console.log(true);
            }
        });
        return ret;
    });
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0]);
});
```

It's easier and you only retrieve value you want to retrieve. Fast to implement and to maintain.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Tz4Ux/)

Comment: thanks, I like your simplistic approach. Though to get the value for the drop down list i had to use :selected as in var $data = $("option:selected", this).val()||$(this).text();  The problem I have now is that when i try to access each individual value from the var as in data[0] I am getting only the first character returned. which of course doesn't help the if statement

Comment: @SteveBeaty you don't need to retrieve the `:selected` as the `.val()` function already do it for you. and sorry I totally missed your point about the data here you check my update

Comment: Hey @TecHunter Check my edit to the original post.  I couldn't of gotten that far without your input.  Though i had to keep the option:selected in the code, on its surface i understand why i shouldnt need it but honestly it didn't work without it.  Perhaps a bug...  Either way thanks again for your help.

Comment: @SteveBeaty oh ok, you should accept someone's answer at least and vote each post helped you. np for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on()` in place of `live()` **(IF your JQuery version supports it)**  **[REASON](http://bitovi.com/blog/2011/04/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live.html)** .  Just modified your jquery a little bit like this and it worked **:**

**JQuery-**

```
$("#submit").on('click', function (e) {

       $("#attendees tr.data").map(function (index, elem) {
           $(this).find('td').each(function(){
           var $data = $(this).html();
           alert($data);
            if ($data == "N/A") {
            alert(true);    
           }
        });
      });
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

**UPDATE:-**

Just check whether there is a selectbox in the `td` . If it is, then you can get its as shown below **:**

```
if($(this).find("select").length > 0)
     {
         alert("found select")
         alert($(this).find("select").val())
     }
```

Demo here **:-**  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cX7cU/3/)** (The updated one showing the value selected in the **selectbox** )

Comment: everything worked except the cell with the drop down box came back as html instead of the value.  any suggestions?

Comment: Just for usability purposes, could I suggest using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` (there were *lots* of alerts being fired...)?

Comment: @SteveBeaty  use `.val()` instead of `.text()` but also check my answer

Comment: @TecHunter please see my response to your answer and by the way for that portion i had to end up using var $data = $("option:selected", this).val()||$(this).text();

Comment: @SteveBeaty You can also check if there is any `selectbox` in a `td` while traversing. And if it is, you can easily get the selected value from it. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things, assuming you're using a recent version of jQuery, you're going to want to replace `live()` with `on()`.

Also, you need to iterate over you cells to find what you're looking for, simply placing it in a variable won't do the trick.

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit' function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //time to iterate over the cells
    $("#attendees tr.data td").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).text() == "N/A") {
            alert("Found it on cell index: " +i);
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to use `.map()` to return an array of the `td` text, you can do:

```
var tdArray = $("#attendees tr.data td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: thanks for your response, this worked for the most part but the cell with the drop down list came back with all the options instead of the one chosen