# post table data from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Good morning ,
I dont know how to send data from html jquery ajax to php and retrieve it.
i was trying to use google sheet api but for the choix:tab i dont get any result .
i want to send the data to php or to mysql but i dont know how to put table in mysql via post method of jquery

```
var nom = $("#nom").val();
var prenom = $("#nom").val();

var tab = [];

$(".choosed").each((index,elem)=> {
    tab.push($(elem).attr("alt"));
})

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gamay.php",
    data:{nom:$("#nom").val(),prenom:$("#prenom").val(),
          service:$("#service").val(),choix:tab,demande:$("#demande").val()
    },
    success: function(response){
        $(".box").hide();
        $(this).attr("disabled",false);
        $(".formations").removeClass("btn-primary");    
        $(".formations").addClass("btn-secondary"); 
        $(".formations").removeClass("choosed");
        $(".box2").toggleClass("transform-active");
        
        $("#saveName").fadeIn(500);
        $("#successDiv").show();
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("KO")
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a html table and you want to get data from this table to send data to php, right? Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805288/jquery-get-values-from-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data: JSON.stringify({
  nom: $("#nom").val(),
  prenom: $("#prenom").val(),
  service: $("#service").val(),
  choix: tab,
  demande: $("#demande").val()
})
```

In your PHP, your may need to use `json_decode($_POST['choix'], true)` to decode the array since it is, itself, a complex value.  But, the others should be available in '$_POST' by simply referring to their key names.

A couple notes about jQuery, avoid using the same selector multiple times (particularly in the same scope).
E.g. You're using `$(".formations")` 3 times.
Instead, variablize it. `var $formations = $(".formations");`, then refer to the `$formations` variable for all 3 statements.  One of the more expensive sides to using jQuery is redundantly selecting/creating jQuery objects.  Don't forget the DRY principle.

The `.removeClass()` method can take multiple class names, separated by spaces.  This can reduce the number of statements you need to use.

Comment: thank you a lot , I just want to ask if could you please tell me how my php file should be cause i still didn't create one and thank you so much .